# MySQLdb update statement

Tags: mysql-python

Im trying to make a MySQL update statement with python, but I keep getting the "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error, while the statement totally works when I try the query in MySQL workbench. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

**Code**

```
self.cur.execute('UPDATE UserAction SET count=%s WHERE user=%s AND action=%s)',
                                     (count, id, action))
```

**Full error**

*1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are causing problems here:

First, you need single quotes around all %s formatters. I'm not familiar with python, but usually you have to use an escape sequence like \' to add quotes.

Second, you seem to have a misplaced close-parenthesis at the end of your statement. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741646/1781207.

```
self.cur.execute('UPDATE UserAction SET count=%s WHERE user=%s AND action=\'%s\'', (count, id, action))
```

Looks like you have an extra ")" inside your SQL statement